# What is the difference between a BRICS member and a BRICS-bank member?

Tags: bangladesh, indonesia

As far as I understand, Bangladesh and Indonesia are members of the BRICS Bank. However, they are not members of the BRICS alliance.

What advantages would Bangladesh and Indonesia be missing out on as opposed to the newly joined six members?

Comment: Bangladesh is a member of the BRICS Development Bank, [but Indonesia isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Development_Bank#Membership), as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> all members of the United Nations could be members of the BRICS bank, however the share of the BRICS member nations can never be less than 55% of voting power.

BRICS alliance is an alliance of "emerging powers", and will accept other "emerging powers" as its members. Bangladesh & Uruguay are not yet considered "emerging powers", therefore not yet invited to become a member of BRICS alliance.

Indonesia is not a member of BRICS New Development Bank (NDB). Indonesia is part of Asian Development Bank (ADB), an initiative of the United Nations, and modeled after the World Bank.

Any country (incl. NATO & Five Eyes) that sanctions or attacks a current BRICS country will not be allowed into the alliance.

Comment: Except, you know, [India has sanctioned China](https://politicstoday.org/india-tightens-sanctions-against-chinese-technology-companies/), and [China has attacked India](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/world/2023/apr/28/india-accuses-china-of-aggressions-amid-border-stalemate) (at least according to the Indian government). *Perhaps* there is some document that says that BRICS countries should not do this, although the answer does not seem to cite it, so who knows. But the practical reality seems to be different.

Comment: "allowed into the alliance" as in BRICS alliance inviting new members.

Comment: The [Sino-Indian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_War?wprov=sfla1) was in 1962, so China and India had already had a military conflict before joining BRIC (in 2010, before it became BRICS with the addition of South Africa). There was also the Sino-Soviet border conflict in 1969. Clearly, past military conflicts are not practically a deal-breaker for joining BRICS. As with any other alliance, BRICS will invite members based on the existing members' perception of their current political interests, not so much past alliances or conflicts.

Comment: Grammar Lesson: "sanctions or attacks" is present tense, and NOT past tense.

Comment: Sure, but you seem to believe that despite (a) not expelling members who have engaged in sanctions or war against each other since joining BRICS, and (b) having founding members who had previously engaged in war against each other, if any non-member ever sanctions or attacks a current member, they will never join BRICS. While that is not a *logically inconsistent* position, I think we have very little reason to think that such a fine distinction is likely to be observed, when the more likely possibility is that membership is based on realpolitik.

Comment: Do Note: Propaganda wars (Psychological Operations), Economic wars (Sanctions, tariff wars), Guerrilla wars (terrorism) & Hot wars (Military invasions) are all part of the "Political" game. (i.e the sanctions on Russia is NATO & Five Eyes playing politics.)